# Como obtener direccion MAC desde nodejs

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Necesito saber si es posible obtener la direccion MAC de un cliente en NodeJS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hay varias soluciones una de ellas podria ser esta :

```
var addr = require('node-macaddress').one();
```

o instalando el modulo [getMac](https://www.npmjs.com/package/getmac)

```
npm install getmac
```

Answer (score 1):

Como dicen en [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19647916/getting-clients-mac-address-on-node-js), a menos que el cliente esté en el mismo segmento de red LAN, no obtendrás la dirección del cliente, si no seguramente del router del cliente.

Al parecer, hay algunas aplicaciones que instaladas en node te darán información de las MAC de los clientes (aunque sea del router) -> https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=Arp

Espero que te valga.